# Installed lubuntu but greeted with a command line

Tags: lubuntu

I installed "lubuntu netinstall 18.04" using the software called UNetbootin. 
Installed it on my laptop and as i boot in im greeted with a lovely "login" into the command line. 
What did i do wrong? Can i fix this?

Comment: Some info about your system would be helpful, especially the video adapter.

Comment: You seem to have a text mode system. Maybe this is what to expect depending on the iso file and what you did with it. *Please edit your original question to answer the following questions:* What is the name of the iso file, that you installed from? Please describe in a detailed way what you did: Where did Unetbootin create its target (in a USB pendrive or in an internal drive)? Did you boot from that target drive and run the installer to install Lubuntu? Was that installer working in graphical mode or text mode?

Comment: Lubuntu netinstall, IIRC, is a minimalist install to let you install what you want from the net. Which desktop environment do you want? (Eg KDE, Gnome, LXDE, etc.). You can log in presumably? Did you try to`sudo apt install` a DE? (apt should pull in the packages needed to give you a GUI, then you can mess with optimising it using specific drivers).